# Use & but still print to the console

Tags: bash

I'd like to find the "cpuinfo" file and tried

```
$ find / -iregex ".*cpuinfo.*" 2>/dev/null &
[1] 7996
```

However, it still print results to the console

```
$ /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask/Casks/cpuinfo.rb
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/distutils/cpuinfo.py
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/distutils/__pycache__/cpuinfo.cpython-36.pyc
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/distutils/cpuinfo.py
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/distutils/cpuinfo.pyc
```

How to hide them entirely background?

Comment: What is the purpose of this?

Comment: Where do you want to print the search result? This command with full output redirected to `/dev/null` makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to hide all output you can redirect stdin and stdout:

```
find / -iregex ".*cpuinfo.*" >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Or with bash:

```
find / -iregex ".*cpuinfo.*" &>/dev/null &
```

Answer (score 0):

To have result of the "cpuinfo" file search available with errors suppressed, execute the command `find` with `screen` utility.

Just start your search with screen detached:

```
screen -dm find / -iregex ".*cpuinfo.*" 2>/dev/null
```

To reattach screen with the command runnung do

```
screen -r
```

Since leading dollar sign `$` is present in your command and search will be performed inside root `/`, consider to execute `find` with `sudo` or as `root` user.